# awk: How can I use [[ and ]] as field separators/delimiters?

Tags: awk

I need to use double square brackets as field separators, both open and closing.
Double backslashing works for one type only, opening or closing, like

`awk -F '\\[\\['` and does not pick up single brackets

but `-F ['\\]\\]''\\[\\[']` or `-F '[\\]\\] \\[\\[]'` picks up single brackets.

Comment: please add sample inout with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-F` takes a regular expression as an argument. `-F '\\[\\[|]]'` should be sufficient. The `[` needs to be escaped to prevent it from starting a bracket expression, but `]` without a matching `[` is treated literally.

Answer (score 0):

or just make it explicit :

```
FS = "[[][[]|[]][]]"
```

This way you don't have to worry about how many backslashes are needed