# Awk using [ and ] as separators (chapter 2), Windows

Tags: awk

I know this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124183/awk-how-can-i-use-and-as-field-separators-delimiters) but I fail to make the examples work.

Under Windows, given the following input from a logfile:

```
[140219UTC10:12:03.338] [inf] [  403] [ServiceManager   ] Success Init loggerbackend
```

I would like to extract the different fields, which is trivial for first 4 using `FS="["`  or `FS="[\\[]"`. I will have to manually sort out `]` but that's doable. Strangely here, my $1 is empty and $2=`140219UTC10:12:03.338]` . Not sure why ?

But what is the **right** solution, so that I can have EITHER `[`  OR `]`  as separator ?

My desired assignment would be something like

```
140219UTC10:12:03.338   |    inf    |      403  |   ServiceManager  |   Success Init loggerbackend
```

I do not mind some empty fields because of spaces.

I am an Windows, using GNU Awk 4.2.1.

Comment: Alternatively `awk '{sub("^\[", ""); gsub("\] +\[|\]", "|")}1' file.log`. Btw, $1 is empty because there's a field before the first "[".

Comment: @AndreWildberg please post your answer as an answer so it can be up/downvoted like all of the other answers so the OP (and others in future) can get the benefit of the community's opinion on your answer to compare to the other answers, and so it can be commented on with comments that are clearly associated with your answer rather than scattered throughout other general comments and you automatically get notified about instead of us having to manually tag you.

Comment: @AndreWildberg regarding the script in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77666526/awk-using-and-as-separators-chapter-2-windows#comment136923982_77666526) - you don't need to escape `]` in a regexp, the regexp delimiter is `/`, not `"` (using `"` means you'd have to double each ```\``` - right now your code would fail with syntax errors as each ```\``` would be consumed by awk converting those strings to regexps), and `] +\[|]` = `]( +\[)?` so you don't have to repeat the `]` and IMO it's slightly clearer.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the regex correction, I actually used `/` but it seems I copied the wrong line. Regarding the answer, I deliberately commented because it doesn't directly answer the question "using [] as separator", it's meant as a hint in a different direction and we all know those don't always qualify as a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- *all lines* start in column #1 with a time/date stamp wrapped in brackets (eg, `[140219UTC10:12:03.338] [inf]`)
- the input delimiters (`[` / `]`) do not show up as data

An alternative `FS` that allows both brackets (`[` / `]`) to serve as input separators:

```
FS = "[][]"  (or -F'[][]')
```

In your sample data the '1st field' is going to be blank since the line *starts* with one of your input delimiters.

Pulling this into a complete script:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="[][]"; OFS="|" } { $1 = $1 } 1' sample.dat
|140219UTC10:12:03.338| |inf| |  403| |ServiceManager   | Success Init loggerbackend
```

If you don't want the leading `|` then there are a few ways to do this, eg:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = "[][]"; OFS = "|" }
      { for (i=1;i<NF;i++) 
            $i = $(i+1)                             # shift all fields one position to the "left"
        NF--                                        # decrement the number of fields
      }
1
' sample.dat

-----------------------------------------

awk '
BEGIN { FS = "[][]"; OFS = "|" }
      { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)                         
            printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)   # manually print fields 2-NF
      }
' sample.dat
```

These both generate:

```
140219UTC10:12:03.338| |inf| |  403| |ServiceManager   | Success Init loggerbackend
```

---

Next issue is the 'extra' empty fields.

**NOTE:** OP's desired output has added some extra white space; for the sake of this answer I'm not going to bother trying to *add* white space.

If we can be guaranteed that all lines contain matching sets of brackets then we can limit ourselves to processing the even-numbered fields, plus the last field, eg:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = "[][]"; OFS = "|" }
      { for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2)
             printf "%s%s", $i, OFS         # print even-numbered fields
        print $NF                           # print last field
      }
' sample.dat
```

This generates:

```
140219UTC10:12:03.338|inf|  403|ServiceManager   | Success Init loggerbackend
```

---

Going a bit further and stripping leading/trailing white space from all fields:

```
awk '
function strip_spaces(fld) {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/,"",fld)
    return fld
}

BEGIN { FS = "[][]"; OFS = "|" }

      { for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) {
            printf "%s%s", strip_spaces($i), OFS
        }
        print strip_spaces($NF)
      }
' sample.dat
```

This generates:

```
140219UTC10:12:03.338|inf|403|ServiceManager|Success Init loggerbackend
```

Comment: Regarding `NF--` - changing the value of `NF` is undefined behavior so some awks will do what you want, others will ignore it, and others still could do anything else with it now or in future.

Answer (score 1):

I almost would have answer this:

```
gawk "/\[/{ gsub(/[][]/,\"#\",$0);} { gsub(/# ?#?/,\"^|\",$0);} 1" file
```

produces:

```
|140219UTC10:12:03.338|inf|  403|ServiceManager   |Success Init loggerbackend
```

P.S. Tested on Windows, and this assumes there are no `#` in your text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'\\[|\\]' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1}1' file

|140219UTC10:12:03.338| |inf| |  403| |ServiceManager   | Success Init loggerbackend
```

first field is the field before the first FS, here it's empty since your data starts with an input field separator.

Since you actually define the fields, not the field separators, it's better to define the field pattern instead

```
$ awk -v FPAT='\\[[^]]+\\]' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1}1' file

[140219UTC10:12:03.338]|[inf]|[  403]|[ServiceManager   ]
```

which captures the fields as shown, but drops the last part which is not wrapped in square brackets.

Since your input is not properly defined there is no proper solution and you need to do some tweaks regardless.

If you use the first approach, you can post process the first output to get the desired format

```
$ awk -F'\\[|\\]' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1}1' file | 
  sed 's/^|//;s/| *|/  |  /g'

140219UTC10:12:03.338  |  inf  |    403  |  ServiceManager   | Success Init loggerbackend
```

Comment: Right, I'm just explaining why.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but does not work on Windows awk.

Comment: Try double quotes instead of single. What works depends on which shell etc you are using. Because of the severe usability problems of the Windows command line, you may have to store the script in a file instead of pass it on the command line.

Comment: @MyICQ WSL? cygwin? gitbash? There is little reason to be stuck at Windows for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -F'([[:space:]]*[][][[:space:]]*)+' -v OFS='|' '{sub("^"FS,""); $1=$1} 1' file
140219UTC10:12:03.338|inf|403|ServiceManager|Success Init loggerbackend
```

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77666526/awk-using-and-as-separators-chapter-2-windows/77667282?noredirect=1#comment136927012_77667282) [@Luuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724039/luuk) tells me that this is the Windows equivalent to the above code:

```
awk -F"([[:space:]]*[][][[:space:]]*)+" -v OFS="|" "{sub(\"^^\"FS,\"\"); $1=$1} 1" file
```

The same thing fleshed out a bit more and with explanation and will work on Windows without the usual associated shenanigans:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "([[:space:]]*[][][[:space:]]*)+"
    OFS = "|"
}
{
    sub("^"FS,"")
    $1 = $1
    print
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        print i, "<" $i ">"
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
140219UTC10:12:03.338|inf|403|ServiceManager|Success Init loggerbackend
1|<140219UTC10:12:03.338>
2|<inf>
3|<403>
4|<ServiceManager>
5|<Success Init loggerbackend>
```

The loop is just there to show you the contents of each field, you can remove it.

Rather than using `[` or `]` separately as a field separator, it uses every sequence of `<optional spaces><[ or ]><optional spaces><[ or ]><optional spaces>` as the field separator.

Since you don't want spaces at the start/end of any field, I'm including spaces before/after/between every `[` or `]` as part of the `FS`. Your example doesn't have any spaces at the end of the line but if they could be there too and need to be removed, add a `sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")` next to the existing `sub()`.

Regarding:

> Strangely here, my $1 is empty and $2=140219UTC10:12:03.338] . Not
> sure why ?

Your line starts with `[` and you set the `FS` to include `[` so there is an empty field before the first `[` on the line. That's why I'm removing that initial `FS` using `sub()`.

Windows has bizarre quoting rules but as long as you save the script in a file and interpret it with `awk -f` as I do above rather than trying to interpret it on the command line with `awk '...'` it should work fine as-is.

Comment: I you really want to do it on Windows as a oneliner, do: `awk -F"([[:space:]]*[][][[:space:]]*)+" -v OFS="|" "{sub(\"^^\"FS,\"\"); $1=$1} 1" file `

Comment: @Luuk Thanks. Don't the `$1`s need to be escaped too?

Comment: No, this works on my windows 11 machine...    the most tricky was the double `^^`  ( On Windows the `$` has no special meaning, but `^` and `%` have ...)

Comment: @Luuk thanks again, I added that script into my answer.

Comment: @Luuk : have you tried using `sub(/\136.../, _)` in lieu of having to double-escape the `^`, and use the unused blank variable as proxy for empty string ? (the first part `\136` only works on `gawk` when used as regex itself instead of string form)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: `awk -F"([[:space:]]*[][][[:space:]]*)+" -v OFS="|" "{sub(\"\136\"FS,\"\"); $1=$1} 1" file` Also works the `\136` needs to be surrounded by `"` which need to be escaped...   (So: `awk "BEGIN{ print \"\122\101\122\105\"; }"` produces a `RARE`)

Comment: @Luuk : what about just `awk -F"([[:space:]]*[][][[:space:]]*)+" -v OFS="|" "sub(\"\136\" FS, _) + (NF = NF)"`  …. does this work ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: Other options, might work too. Please provide a new answer when you have a better one, or ask a new question when you have a new question.

Comment: @Luuk : i haven't dealt with windows for so long it's hard to even picture what does and doesn't work under that wretched double-quoting regime

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: [Escape double quotes in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter), when that does not answer your question, you can ask a new one 